# continuous function $h(x)=\sup\{f(t)\colon t\le x\}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Assuming $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, how do you prove that the following function is continuous?

$$h(x)=\sup\{f(t): t\leq x\}$$

Comment: What are your thoughts? - i.e. what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have no idea, maybe some hint?

Comment: Can you prove that the function $h$ is increasing? Do you know anything about possible discontinuities of monotone functions?

Comment: See also: [Prove functions defined by sup and inf are continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/748639) and [If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $F(x) = \sup f([a,x])$. Prove that $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ .](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1014244)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I asked Jan 6 '14 at 22:57

Comment: @aiki93 One thing is that age is not the most important thing when closing as duplicates, older question can be closed as a duplicate of a newer one. There are many discussions about this on meta, for example [Topics declared as duplicates in which order?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10328) and [other questions linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/10328).

Comment: But the main reason I voted to close as a duplicate was that when I looked at the question it already was in the [close votes review queue](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/1160712) with two close votes with the close reason [missing context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) - so it was very likely going to be closed anyway. To close as a duplicate seemed to me as a slightly better option. It is less harsh to the asker. And, moreover, the duplicate links directs users to other question(s) where the same thing is answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x<y$ and $|f(t)-f(x)|\le \delta$ for all $t\in [x,y]$ then
$$
h(x) \le h(y) \le h(x)+\delta
$$
since
$$ 
h(y) = \max\{h(x),\sup\{f(t)\colon t \in [x,y]\}\} \le \max\{h(x),f(x)+\delta\} \le h(x)+\delta.
$$

Comment: why $h(y) \le h(x)+\delta.$

Comment: explanation added...